# Determine the active Google Slides file from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have an Apps Script project that is bound to a Google Sheets file, and I want to manipulate a Google Slides presentation. Specifically, I want to replace all the text in it.

I can use this command:

```
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().replaceAllText(findText, replaceText);
```

But, unfortunately the Script Editor doesn't know the active presentation.

How do I "get" or "activate" a Slides file?

To be clear, I am not using the Slides API in JavaScript, but rather a script in the Apps Script editor. It's slightly different.

Comment: You can't. `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation` requires the Script Project to be bound to a Google Slides file - you state it is bound to a Google Sheets file instead. Your recourse is to use one of the other `SlidesApp.openBy____` methods that return a `Presentation`. These other methods will require you to know the Drive File ID or URL of the Slides presentation. You can get the ID with `DriveApp` (by searching by name) or manually (from the URL). If you are constantly changing which presentation you are working with, it sounds like you should deploy an add-on.

Comment: ok makes sense. I have to call the Slides with a request instead. Thanks for the fast response!